# Copied/Imported Xen Server VM can't see all CPUs?

Tags: central-processing-unit, xenserver, copy, import

I have installed a new Xen Host Server with more cores. I attempted both a copy and import of the VM from the old Host. When I attempt to increase the CPUs, the option only shows me what was available on the old Host. If I create a new VM on the new Host, I can see all of the CPUs. Why  is that? How can I resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my issue. I did locate a document detailing how to make the changes to the sockets and cores using the XSCONSOLE. However, the part used to change the cores would not work for me.

The solution was to Copy, Move, Export/Import or Restore the VMs from backup to the new Host. Then create a new VM on the new host using the appropriate OS version that matches the VM's OS that your are working with. Don't start the new VM. This new VM on the new Host is just the lattice work.

Convert this new VM to a Template. Detach the VHD from the Imported (etc,) VM. Now, use the template you created to create a new VM with the specification of the Imported (etc.) VM. Take the defaults on the VHD size. Don't start it.

Now, detach the default 32GB VHD and attach the VHD from the VM you imported. Start the VM and it will boot fine. **NOTE:** Make sure to use the correct boot configuration (i.e. BIOS - UEFI) as on the VM that was Imported (etc) when created a new VM on the new Host using the template you created. You can now change the sockets and cores as desired. Should you have any questions, feel free to ask.